# How to bring forward a integer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

This is activityresult1

```
Button buttonorder;
TextView textviewcard;
private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 10;
int[] image ={R.drawable.friednoodle, R.drawable.friedrice, R.drawable.steamfish,R.drawable.tehice};
String[] item = {"Fried Noodle", "Fried Rice", "Steam Fish","Iced Tea"};
String[] description = {"Classic Chinese stir fried noodle with prawn and Pork", "Special sauce Fried Rice using indian rice", "HongKong Style Steamed Fish ","HongKong classical iced tea"};
String[] cost={"6","5","25","2"};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activityresult1);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String strcardnumber = extras.getString("Card Number");
    textviewcard = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewcard);
    textviewcard.setText("Welcome, " + strcardnumber + " !" + "\nPlease select the food you want ! : ");

    itemList = new ArrayList<DataInfo>();
    itemList.add(new DataInfo(item[0], image[0], description[0], cost[0]));
    itemList.add(new DataInfo(item[1], image[1], description[1], cost[1]));
    itemList.add(new DataInfo(item[2], image[2], description[2], cost[2]));
    itemList.add(new DataInfo(item[3], image[3], description[3], cost[3]));

    final MenuAdapter adapter = new MenuAdapter(this);

    ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    LVAdapter lvAdapter = new LVAdapter(this, itemList);
    //listView.setAdapter(lvAdapter);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    for (int i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
        adapter.addData(String.valueOf(i), item[i], image[i], description[i], cost[i]);
    }

    buttonorder = (Button) findViewById(R.id.suborder);
    buttonorder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
        String[] a = adapter.getQuantity();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Noodle: " + a[0] + "\nRice: " + a[1] + "\nSteam fish: " + a[2] + "\nIced tea: " + a[3], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

          int sum = Integer.parseInt(adapter.getQuantity()[0])*Integer.parseInt(cost[0]) +
                    Integer.parseInt(adapter.getQuantity()[1])*Integer.parseInt(cost[1]) +
                    Integer.parseInt(adapter.getQuantity()[2])*Integer.parseInt(cost[2]) +
                    Integer.parseInt(adapter.getQuantity()[3])*Integer.parseInt(cost[3]);

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(activityresult1.this, activityresult2.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("sum",sum);
            startActivity(myIntent);

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), activityresult2.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("Noodle quantity", adapter.getQuantity()[0]);
            bundle.putString("Rice quantity", adapter.getQuantity()[1]);
            bundle.putString("Fish quantity", adapter.getQuantity()[2]);
            bundle.putString("Iced tea", adapter.getQuantity()[3]);
            bundle.putInt("sum", sum);
            bundle.putBoolean("ANI", adapter.getItem(0).isAddInisCheck());//add noodle ingredients
            bundle.putBoolean("ARI", adapter.getItem(1).isAddInisCheck()); // add rice ingredients
            bundle.putBoolean("AFI", adapter.getItem(2).isAddInisCheck());// add fish ingredients
            bundle.putBoolean("AIT", adapter.getItem(3).isAddInisCheck()); // add ice tea ingredients
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });
}
```

how do i sent the calculated sum from activityresult1 to activityresult2

```
  static public String txtOrder ="";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activityresult2);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String strfnq = bundle.getString("Noodle quantity");
    String strfrq = bundle.getString("Rice quantity");
    String strfsq = bundle.getString("Fish quantity");
    String stricq = bundle.getString("Iced tea");
    Integer strsum = bundle.getInt("sum");

    boolean addNingc = bundle.getBoolean("ANI");
    boolean addRingc = bundle.getBoolean("ARI");
    boolean addFingc = bundle.getBoolean("AFI");
    boolean addTingc = bundle.getBoolean("AIT");
  //  boolean addmoneyc = bundle.getBoolean("AMY");

    Intent mIntent = getIntent();
    int sum = mIntent.getIntExtra("sum",strsum);

    TextView costtext = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.costtext);
    costtext.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("sum"));

    TextView foodorders = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.foodordershow);
    foodorders.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("Quantity"));

    String addNdlThing = "";
    if (addNingc) { 
        addNdlThing = " with addition of ingredients";
    }

    String addRlThing = "";
    if (addRingc) {
        addRlThing = " with addition of ingredients";
    }

    String addSlThing = "";
    if ( addFingc) {
        addSlThing = " with addition of ingredients";
    }

     String addTeac = "";
    if ( addTingc ) {
        addTeac = " with addition of ingredients";
    }

    foodorders = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.foodordershow);
    if(strfnq.equals("") && strfrq.equals("") && strfsq.equals("")&& stricq.equals("")){
        txtOrder = "Sorry, You've not ordered any thing , please return to previous menu to order";
    }else if (!strfnq.equals("") && !strfrq.equals("") && !strfsq.equals("")&& stricq.equals("")) {
        txtOrder = "Thank you , You've ordered\n" + strfnq + " fried noodle" + addNdlThing +" and\n"+ strfrq
                + " fried rice" + addRlThing +" and\n" + strfsq + " Steam fish " + addSlThing + "and\n" + stricq + " Steam fish " + addTeac;
    } else {
        txtOrder = "Thank you , You've ordered\n";
        if(!strfnq.equals("")){
            txtOrder = txtOrder + strfnq + " fried noodle" + addNdlThing;
        }
        if(!strfrq.equals("")){
            txtOrder = txtOrder + strfrq + " fried rice" + addRlThing;
        }
        if(!strfsq.equals("")){
            txtOrder = txtOrder + strfsq + " Steam fish" + addSlThing;
        }
        if(!stricq.equals("")){
            txtOrder = txtOrder + stricq + " Iced Tea"+ addTeac;
        }
    }
    foodorders.setText(txtOrder);
}
```

i want to calculate the money spent in result1 and display it in result 2 
i have tried using the method they written at  the bottom but it dont work as i dont know what to fill in for some . please help me , i really need help on this , and i am typing alot to make the word count so i can post , as i have too much codes they say , and please stop disliking this post , dont be such persons , like this and it will be happy for both parties , asking question dont mean i am  stupid

Comment: I don't see why this was downvoted at all, let alone twice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sent the value of the `sum` to the next `activity` and get it via `Bundle` in the other `activity` like this. Think that your are sending it to the `activity B`

```
Intent i= new Intent(this,B.class);
i.putExtra("sum",sum);
startActivity(i);
```

you can send the `context` to the `activity B` through either one of the following `this`,`getActivity()`,`getApplicationContext()`

Then in`activity B` you can add these lines in `onCreate()` method, to get the passed content

```
 Bundle MainActivityData= getIntent().getExtras();
 int sum= MainActivityData.getString("sum");
```

Comment: sorry i dont get it , can you email me at wenhan999@hotmail.com

Comment: i tried adding it in , but , it have red lines under it

Comment: The first line  , Intent(this,B.class); what do i write for B , and after that i copy the bundle activity but cannot

Comment: Sorry, I was not online. did you got it fixed

Comment: For `B` type the name of the `activity` that you need to pass the `sum` value ( it also must be the same activity that opens when a `button` is clicked or any `widget` being selected from the current activity). For starting a new activity we need to send the current `context` to it, for that we need to use `this`, `getActivity()`,`getApplicationContext()` in the line `Intent i= new Intent(this,B.class);` as the first `parameter`.

Comment: When `startActivity(i)` lines runs, it start the `activity B`( which is the `activity` you need to pass the `sum` value) with the `sum` value being passed to it through` putExtra`. To get this passed values, we need to use a `Bundle`. You need to use `Bundle MainActivityData= getIntent().getExtras();
 int sum= MainActivityData.getString("sum");` in the `new activity's` `onCreate method` to get the passed values. Hope you understood it prior to my explanation

Comment: i didnt fix it , i dont know whats wrong with it D;

Comment: could u sent me a email so i can share my codes with you and you can help me take a look pls?

Comment: send your code to `codsop256@yandex.com` or else you can edit your question with adding all of your work

Comment: hi did u receive it ? please return me a email

Comment: I recieved it, I'll look it and let you know